# What to do after files when creating c# in visual studio code

Tags: c#

I have been searching for an answer to this question. When I make a python in vsc, I add .py after the file name. When I make a java file I add .java after file name. For c# I don't know what to add. I tried .exe, it gives me  this symbol "*". I tried .cs, and it gives me the same symbol.

Comment: C# source code files use ".cs" as file ending by convention. Not sure what "symbol" you are talking about

Comment: you can install c# extension from the market place, @id:ms-vscode.csharp

Comment: Hi Goblinkilller, did the answer help clarify your question. If yes please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This will also help others understand you've found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.Java is to Java files as .CS is to C# files.**

Additionally you can install the C# extension from VSCode

> 1. Go to Extensions (Ctrl+Shift+X)
> 2. Search for @id:ms-vscode.csharp and install